# Angular get exception text from spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, exception

```
        this.apiServiceService.generateToken(authRequest).subscribe(
          data => {}, 
          err => {
            console.log(err.error);
        })

; }
```

Output is

```
{"timestamp":"2020-05-07T16:08:16.133+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Bad credentials!","path":"/api/authenticate"}
```

can i get only message from this output? thanks

Comment: did you try : err.error.message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for this, Just use `console.log(err.error.message);` to get the message being printed.

```
var err = JSON.parse(err.error); 
console.log(err.message);
```

Comment: This returns undefined, i want to get this from err output: "message":"Bad credentials!"

Comment: what does your console.log(err); print you.

Comment: var err = JSON.parse(err.error); 
        console.log(err.message);